# Can't join domain on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, domain

When I try to change my computer's domain, I get an error dialog saying:

> This machine is already joined to a cloud domain and cannot be
>   subsequently joined to an Active Directory domain

How do I fix this problem? I have to change the domain of my system.

Comment: Are you able to remove the computer from the domain at all without trying to change it at the same time? I've never seen this error. Maybe the AD domain is hosted on a cloud server and you might need the admin to remove the computer from that domain.

Comment: No I couldnt able to remove the system from the domain

Comment: I thought the upcoming windows 10 is the only one that supports joining what there calling a "cloud domain" joining. That settings is usually only reachable from the metro style settings interface and not regular desktop interface. Try looking there.

Comment: Is this Windows 8 or 8.1 and is it professional version?

Comment: Can you go to [Settings] [UserAccounts] [Work Access].
What do you see there? Can you "join" or "leave" ?

Also, do you log in with a normal account (for this preferably one which can escalate to admin rights) or with an Microsoft account?